# Including a Javascript file in a splitted Shiny App

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I want to include a Javascript file within my Shiny App to highlight rows of two tables (see code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/54thG/)).

I've searched how to do this and only came across solutions for [normal structured Shiny Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599268/include-a-javascript-file-in-shiny-app), [Dashboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281051/how-to-include-a-remote-javascript-file-in-a-shiny-dashboard-app) or [single-file apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799296/include-javascript-file-in-a-single-file-shiny-app). However, I am using a structure for my app proposed by [Dean Attali](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/split-code), where the main UI and server are inside a file called "app.R" and each (sub)menu is within seperate UI and Server files.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
├── app.R
└── server
   └── someserverfile1.R
   └── someserverfile2.R
└── ui
   └── someuifile1.R
   └── someuifile2.R
└── www
   └── style.css
   └── highlight.js
```

I tried including the script call

```
tags$head(tags$script(src="highlight.js"))
```

in the **app.R** [here in ui <- tagList() and ui <- tagList(navbarPage())] and in the **someuifile1.R**, which consists of a tabPanel with a sidebarLayout. 
In either case, the html-header of the resulting app does not change.

Does anyone have an idea where to put the call?

Comment: can you check `source(... local=T)` is present when you're loading these files

Comment: Yes, while sourcing all the server and ui files local=T is set. Do I need to explicitly source the JS file too?