# mapview and shiny: how to change the color palette interactively

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, reactive

I would like to use the `mapview` package - it is quite fast - in shiny.
In order to render the `mapview` object the `@map` trick works like a charm.

However, as opposed to `ggplot2`, making the `mapview_leaflet` object reactive, is quite complicated. In my shiny app, I would like to make the color palette interactive. Is that possible?

```
library(mapview)
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderLeaflet({
    req(input$obs)
    rws <- input$obs
    mapview(breweries91[1:rws,])@map
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:", min = 1, max = nrow(breweries91@data), value = nrow(breweries91@data))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput('test')
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This would be a ***much*** better question if you showed a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable reproducible example app and then describe or show how you need it modified to do what you want.

Comment: the code is taken from https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/58 
It makes the data set used reactive.

Comment: I think that helps. You might want to add the line to load the data used in that code (I think it's builtin to some package) and describe your desired output vs what this generates a bit more.

Comment: The mapview function has the argument col.regions.
Perhaps its enough to integrate this additional argument in combination with a `radioButton`

Comment: I would give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, that by making the input data and hence the mapview object reactive, mapview and shiny work like a charm with the @map hack. In conjunction with the [leaflet-easyprint plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343316/shiny-leaflet-easyprint-plugin) it is a very useful tool for creating and exporting maps.