# How to get Leaflet JS Plugins Displaying in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to use the the grouped layer control plugin in Shiny. I have been able to get it render and work perfectly in leaflet alone (see [here](https://nosheal.github.io/COVID19-Supply-Chains/prototype.html)) but when I try and run this in Shiny, the grouped layer control plugin does not render at all (see my attempt  [here](https://nosheal.shinyapps.io/COVID19_SUPPLY_CHAINS/).

I have tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343316/shiny-leaflet-easyprint-plugin) example, and I've also tried to use [this](https://gist.github.com/bhaskarvk/f3e3a609fa901b4fefea624fcb1d863a) format, and I think hat the issue that I should not be using htmlDependencies to call javascript plugins but I've tried for quite some time and I am lost as to how to get this to work in shiny.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows: (data files can be found on my [github](https://github.com/nosheal/COVID19-Supply-Chains/tree/master/Data).

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(RJSONIO)
library(readxl)
library(widgetframe)
library(lattice)
library(DT)

#Load the Data
df_for_maps <- readRDS("Data/df_for_maps.rds")
swabs <- readRDS("Data/swabs.rds")
nonwoven <- readRDS("Data//nonwoven.rds")

### LOAD MAPPING PREREQS


#font pluging
fontawesomePlugin <- htmlDependency("fontawesome", "5.13.0",
                                    src = c(href = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0"),
                                    stylesheet = "css/all.css"
)
#add dependencies
addDependencies <- function(map) {
  map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, leafletDependencies$easyButton(),
                        leafletDependencies$fontawesome())

  map
}



# Function for creating circle markers given a data set
createCircleMarkersWithData <- function(map, dataSet, clusterId, group, fillColor, icon) {
  jsFuncStr = str_replace_all(str_interp("
    function(cluster) {
      var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
      return new L.DivIcon({
                                               html: '<div style=\"background-color:${fillColor}; color: white\"><span>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div><span>',
                                               className: 'marker-cluster', iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40)
                                             });
    }", list(fillColor = fillColor)), "[\r\n]" , "")
  addAwesomeMarkers(map,
                    data = dataSet,
                    popup = dataSet$popup,
                    icon = awesomeIcons(
                      icon = icon,
                      library = "fa",
                      markerColor = fillColor,
                      iconColor = "#ffffff"
                    ),
                    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                      iconCreateFunction = JS(jsFuncStr)
                    ),
                    clusterId = clusterId,
                    layerId = dataSet$layerId,
                    group = group)
}


# define colors

sc_color <- colorFactor(c("purple", "darkred"), domain = df_for_maps$purpose)

########

# Define UI for application that draws the mapp
ui <- fluidPage(

    navbarPage("COVID-19 Supply Chains", id="nav",

               tabPanel("Interactive map",
                        div(class="outer",

                            #leafletOutput
                            leafletOutput("mymap")
                        )
               ),

               tabPanel("Data explorer",

                        hr(),
                        DT::dataTableOutput("ziptable")
               )
    )


)



# Define server logic required to draw the map
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #grouped layer control plugin
  groupedLayerControlPlugin <- htmlDependency("leaflet-groupedlayercontrol", "0.61",
                                              src = c(href = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol/gh-pages/src/"),
                                              script = "leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js",
                                              stylesheet = "leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.css"
  )

  # A function that takes a plugin htmlDependency object and adds
  # it to the map. This ensures that however or whenever the map
  # gets rendered, the plugin will be loaded into the browser.
  registerPlugin <- function(map, plugin) {
    map$dependencies <- c(map$dependencies, list(plugin))
    map
  }

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(data = df_for_maps) %>% 
        # add layers of maps (decided to provide three options)
        addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>%
        registerPlugin(groupedLayerControlPlugin) %>%
        registerPlugin(fontawesomePlugin) %>%

        onRender("function(el, x, data) {
        var baseLayers = {
            'Toner Lite': this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Toner Lite'),
        };

        var groupedOverlays = {
            'Testing': {
                'Swabs': this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Swabs'),
            },
            'Surgical Masks': {
                'Nonwoven Fabrics': this.layerManager.getLayerGroup('Nonwoven Fabric'),

            }
        };

        var Options = {
          groupCheckboxes: true
        };

        console.log(L.control.groupedLayers);
        L.control.groupedLayers(baseLayers, groupedOverlays, Options).addTo(this);
    }", data = df_for_maps) %>%
        # set the boundary of the map so that the user cannot zoom out of one world 
        # view of the map
        setMaxBounds(lng1 = 210,
                     lat1 = 89.45016124669523,
                     lng2 = -210,
                     lat2 = -87.71179927260242) %>%

        # add mini map on bottom right corner with collapse option
        addMiniMap(
          tiles = providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
          toggleDisplay = T
        ) %>%

        #1. Swabs
        createCircleMarkersWithData(dataSet = swabs,
                                    fillColor = "darkred",
                                    icon = "fa-syringe",
                                    clusterId = "Swabs",
                                    group = "Swabs") %>%
        #2. Nonwoven Fabrics
        createCircleMarkersWithData(dataSet = nonwoven,
                                    fillColor = "purple",
                                    icon = "fa-head-side-mask",
                                    clusterId = "NonWoven",
                                    group = "Nonwoven Fabric") %>%
        # add button that zooms out to zoom level 1 of the map (showing the entire world map)
        addEasyButton(easyButton(
          icon = "fa-globe",
          title = "Zoom to Level 1",
          onClick = JS("
                 function(btn, map) {
                 map.setZoom(1);
                 }")
        )
        ) %>% 

        #add layer control option for clusters and map type 
        #addLayersControl(
        #baseGroups = c("OSM(Default)", "Google", "Toner Lite", "NatGeoWorldMap"),
        #overlayGroups = c("Swabs", "Nonwoven Fabrics"),
        # collapsable table
        # options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE)
        #) %>% 
        # add legend (table) that shows which color represents which country of origin (color key) - bottom left (due to mini map)
        addLegend(position = c("bottomleft"),
                  values = df_for_maps$purpose,
                  pal = sc_color,
                  title = "Purpose"
        ) 


    })

    output$ziptable <- DT::renderDataTable({
        df <- df_for_maps %>%
          mutate(Action = paste('<a class="go-map" href="" data-lat="', lat, '" data-long="', long, '"><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i></a>', sep=""))

    })

    conditionalPanel("false", icon("crosshair"))
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```